# Perl: unable to use LWP::Parallel::UserAgent for HTTPS websites

Tags: perl, https

I'm unable to use perl module LWP::Parallel::UserAgent for https websites. The following is the code I use:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::Parallel::UserAgent qw(:CALLBACK);
use HTTP::Request; 

my $BrowserName = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36";

my $pua = LWP::Parallel::UserAgent->new();
$pua->agent( $BrowserName );
$pua->nonblock('true');
$pua->in_order  (1);
$pua->duplicates(0);
$pua->timeout   (10);
$pua->redirect  (2);
$pua->remember_failures ( 1 );

$url = "https://www.squeezemind.it";

my $res = $pua->register( HTTP::Request->new('GET', $url), \&gestione_risposta, 4096 );

my $entries = $pua->wait();

# Leggo le risposte
foreach (keys %$entries) {
  my $res = $entries->{$_}->response;
  print "\n\nAnswer for '",$res->request->url, "' was ", $res->code,": ", $res->message;  
}


sub gestione_risposta {

  my($html_content, $response, $protocol, $entry) = @_;

  if( !$response->is_success || $response->code != 200 ) { return C_ENDCON; }  

  if( length($html_content) ) {    
    # Bla Bla
  }

  return undef; 

}
```

It **works well for http** but if you try to change $url with a https website it fails.

For https://www.squeezemind.it:

Error code: 500
Message: **Can't locate object method "get_cipher" via package "IO::Socket::INET" at /usr/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/https.pm line 119**

For https://www.stackoverflow.com:

Error code: 402
Message: **Unexpected EOF while reading response**

The system is up to date. Suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Net::Curl::Multi would be so much faster (but you lose the familiar LWP interface and portability to Windows)

Comment: *"The system is up to date."* - whatever this exactly means regarding the versions of the software you are using. Please include the versions of LWP, LWP::Protocol::https, IO::Socket::SSL, Net::SSLeay and openssl you are using into the question - see [here](https://pastebin.com/Y5MD2auR) for a script to do this. Also please run your code with `perl -MIO::Socket::SSL=debug9 program.pl` and add the output to your question. And please try it also with a simple LWP::UserAgent instead of LWP::Parallel::UserAgent.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use a user agent designed for parallelism to begin with, such as [Mojo::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent) or [Net::Async::HTTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Async::HTTP).

Comment: Re "*The system is up to date.*", That's not true. The call to `get_cipher` isn't on line 119 of the latest version of LWP::Protocol::https

Comment: I installed all modules using cpan on an up to date Ubuntu. I don't know if cpan installs not updated modules or so on. These are the installed versions:

LWP 6.36
LWP::Protocol::https 6.07
IO::Socket::SSL 2.056
Net::SSLeay 1.84

Answer (score 2):

From your code:

```
$pua->nonblock('true');
```

When looking at the code of LWP::Parallel::UserAgent it looks like non-blocking support for HTTPS is totally broken: `https` support is implement in LWP::Parallel::Protocol::https which derives from LWP::Parallel::Protocol::http for [doing the actual connection](https://metacpan.org/source/MSOUTH/ParallelUserAgent-2.62/lib/LWP/Parallel/Protocol/https.pm#L31). The relevant code in [sub _connect](https://metacpan.org/source/MSOUTH/ParallelUserAgent-2.62/lib/LWP/Parallel/Protocol/http.pm#L100):

```
103     unless ($nonblock) {
104       # perform good ol' blocking behavior
105       #
106       # this method inherited from LWP::Protocol::http
107       $socket = $self->_new_socket($host, $port, $timeout);
108       # currently empty function in LWP::Protocol::http
109       # $self->_check_sock($request, $socket);
110     } else {
111       # new non-blocking behavior
...
116       $socket =
117         IO::Socket::INET->new(Proto => 'tcp', # Timeout => $timeout,
118                               $self->_extra_sock_opts ($host, $port));
```

One can see that for the (default) blocking case the code uses the functionality of `LWP::Protocol::http`, but for the non-blocking case it directly uses `IO::Socket::INET` - and not `IO::Socket::SSL` for HTTPS. But LWP::Protocol::http (which is used later) actually expects a SSL socket and tries to call `get_cipher` on it. This results in the error you see:

> Can't locate object method "get_cipher" via package "IO::Socket::INET" at /usr/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/https.pm line 119

When not using non-blocking support the code seems to work instead.

As for HTTPS in general in this module see [README.SSL](https://metacpan.org/source/MSOUTH/ParallelUserAgent-2.62/README.SSL):

```
 ** DISCLAIMER: https support is pretty buggy as of now. i haven't **
 ** had time to test much of it, so feel free to see if it works   **
 ** for you, but don't expect it to :-)
```

In other words: you should probably use a different module to get reliable support for HTTPS.

Comment: Hello Steffen, by removing the non-blocking support the code still not works. I receive always the error Sysread Error: Resource temporarily unavailable

I will try to use a different approach

Comment: @user3817605: I would say that the module is broken regarding HTTPS. It likely assumes that non-blocking SSL works like non-blocking TCP - which it doesn't.